# Brace expansion with range in fish shell

Tags: shell, fish, brace-expansion

In bash, I can do the following

```
$ echo bunny{1..6}
bunny1 bunny2 bunny3 bunny4 bunny5 bunny6
```

Is there a way to achieve the same result in fish?

Comment: As an aside for those less familiar with `fish`: `fish` does support brace expansion, but only with _lists_ (e.g., `echo b{ar,az}`), not _ranges_.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The short answer is `echo bunny(seq 6)`

Longer answer: In keeping with fish's philosophy of replacing magical syntax with concrete commands, we should hunt for a Unix command that substitutes for the syntactic construct `{1..6}`. `seq` fits the bill; it outputs numbers in some range, and in this case, integers from 1 to 6. fish (to its shame) omits a help page for `seq`, but it is a standard Unix/Linux command.

Once we have found such a command, we can leverage command substitutions. The command `(foo)bar` performs command substitution, expanding `foo` into an array, and may result in multiple arguments. Each argument has 'bar' appended.

Comment: @chepner: It doesn't matter. fish shell automatically defines `seq` if it doesn't exist, as certain parts of fish source depend on it to exist.

Comment: Since this is the first result for "fish brace expansion"... It is worth noting that fish does do simple brace expansion with commas. e.g. `echo {foo,bar}` or `mkdir --parents /tmp/{folder1,folder2,folder3}` results in /tmp/folder1, /tmp/folder2, /tmp/folder3. More info @ http://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/index.html#expand

Comment: @wviana Try `jot -c 26 a z 1`

Comment: @wviana: a self contained answer: `printf '%b' (printf '\\\\x%02X ' (seq 97 122))`

Comment: What about `touch file{01..10}`, how do you do that in `fish` shell?

Comment: You can pass a format string to seq. `touch file(seq -f %02g 10)`

Comment: @109149 this should also work `touch file(seq -w 10)`